# What does () => className means in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking at react's tutorial [page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/tutorial.html), and it shows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
                                             // ^ this part
```

What does it means? Is it equal to:

```
function() {
  return HelloWorldApp
}
```

If it so, why not using:

```
HelloWorldApp
```

directly?

Comment: function that returns HelloWorldApp is not same as HelloWorldApp

Comment: The reason you would use a function is to make it lazy loading. That way the class is not actually resolved until you use the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's a function that doesn't need any arguments and returns `HelloWorldApp`. It's equivalent to:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', function() {
    return HelloWorldApp;
});
```

As for why it needs a function and not just the React component, I'm not sure. Perhaps it's just an API decision by React Native.